# How to test a package which requires Composite index? Go Datastore

Tags: go, datastore

How can I test a package which requires a composite index? I have the index.yaml file in the package but it seems goapp doesn't pick it. Is there any way that I can tell to goapp to read the index.yaml file?

Comment: How do you know it is not picking it up? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: I get  ``data: no rows in result set`` although the rows are supposed to exist

Comment: Can you show some code, perhaps your index.yaml file?